# how to write output in a file as dictionary not string

Tags: python-3.x

im running analysis on a huge file which take several hours to finish and result is a dictionary which i need for next steps and i want to save the output in a file to keep it. but when i write the output in file, it converts the dictionary output to str and saves it, but python can not interpret the saved str as dictionary in future
for example my output dictionary is

```
output={a:[1,2]}
```

when i save it , its being saved as :

```
'{a:[1,2]}' #can not be interpreted as dictionary by python anymore for further use in future!
```

is there anyway so i could save my output as dictionary in a file or is there any way python could convert string back to dictionary from a file?!

Comment: `pickle`, `json`, `sqlite`

Comment: To load the already "saved as a string dictionary", you could use `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian ast.literal_eval works well for small files, but im working with human genome sequence which is 3GB, and ast gives Memory error even though i have 64GB RAM computer.

Comment: I've mentioned as a way to *rescue* the data that is *"already saved"* in this format. I do not recommend that you continue to save it using this format (and hence there is no need to use `ast.literal_eval()` further).

Comment: so which format do you recommend me to save , consider having a single 3GB dictionary as output of one analysis , how can i save it to be able to use it in future?!

Comment: I don't know. To avoid loading everything into memory, you could try `shelve` (read the docs carefully, to make sure that the changes are stored back to disk). "human genome sequence" is rather specific case;  look for specialized formats e.g., [`FM-index` to allow compression of the input text while still permitting fast substring queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM-index)

Answer (score 0):

If the dictionary contains solely of values of simple types, then you can use `dump()` and `load()` from the `json` module to produce and retrieve a text representation.

The representations produced by `str()` are not meant to be valid Python in all cases. It might be possible to reparse the representations produced by `repr()`, but `json` is a safe bet, and it's cross-programming-language and cross platform.

If the dictionary contains non-simple types, the `json` module has provisions allowing yout to provide your own marshalling/unmarshalling for them.

Comment: i work with human genome which produces a single 3GB dictionary..
i used json as below:

    >>> import json
    >>> file=open('output_chr_fasta_reader.txt','r')
    >>> data=json.load(file)
but it gives the following eror:
ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

or with data=json.loads(file)
gives this error:
TypeError: expected string or buffer

are these errors because of the big size of my dictionary?!

Comment: ``json`` will only load data written in JSON format. You have to change the original program to use ``json.dump()`` instead of writing the dictionary directly. As to the 3GiB, it should be OK if you have the RAM. The performance of the ``json`` functions should be linear, O(n).